# Distribution of a perfect die in infinity

Tags: probability, statistics

**PROBLEM**

I have a classic die with 6 edges. The die is fair, that is, the probability of each outcome is 1/6.
My question is: how to prove that in infinity the distribution will converge to (1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6).

**SOLUTION ATTEMPT**

This is a similar problem to proving that when tossing a coin, in infinity we will have distribution (1/2, 1/2). On the one hand, this seems obvious. On the other hand, I don't know how to formally prove it.

Comment: Have you heard of the [Strong Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it suffices to write that based on strong the law of large numbers the distribution will (almost surely) converge to (⅙,...⅙) ?

Comment: Well you need to show first that the expected distribution is (1/6,...,1/6), but then you can apply SLLN.

Comment: That the probabilities must be equal is the definition of "fair" in the context of the question. This need not be shown. That the frequencies tend to those probabilities with probability $1$ is the content of the mentioned law.